# Not getting the expected fields for rss feeds

Tags: angularjs, rss, google-api

I'm using google's feed api to grab some RSS feeds (I'm building this in Angular).  I'm able to get this to work.

```
function parseFeed (url) {
    return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/loadv=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
}
```

I have an issue:
For some RSS feeds, I'm getting back data as I expect.  The fields are 'author', 'content', 'contentSnippet', 'publishedDate', 'title'.  For other feeds, the 'publishedDate' field is blank.  When I examine the original website's XML, they have a field called 'pubDate' instead.

Any suggestions on how best to deal with this?  I am trying to grab data from a few RSS sources, and sort them by publication date.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check if publishDate is blank or not and process accordingly. Also, if publishDate is not set you can check if pubDate key exists with the data, and then process logic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mat.  The issue is pubDate is not in the data I get back...I don't know why.